# What is a scope in laravel and what is the cons and pros to use it?

Tags: laravel-5.8

When should we use scopes in laravel and what are the advantages?

```
public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It automatically adds extra conditions for SQL query for model (which are needed and which would be applied across the entire model).

Saving you time and effort instead of including repetitive code here and there to add these extra conditions every time a model is fetched. It effectively saves you time, you can also make-do without it by adding it by hand where applicable. it is like `syntactic sugar` lets say.

A **major advantage** is that if at a later time you want to update the conditions (eg your requirements change) you can **easily do it in one place instead of browsing through entire code** to find the extra conditions and update them.

For example take a look [at this article about scopes in Laravel](https://dev.to/bertheyman/the-magic-of-query-scopes-in-laravel-pfp)

Let's say for example that you want your model to satisfy some conditions (for each model call, ie global scope). For example `updated_at > some timestamp` AND `type = some type`. Instead of adding these conditions every time you call your model methods you add a (global) scope which includes them by default for every call. Like it was said, it is simply a time-saver instead of having repetitive and error-prone code here and there.